# I have a gridview i have customize gridview using labels .. i wanna copy the label in cell 2 to textbox outside gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview i have customize gridview using labels .. i wanna copy the label in cell 2 to textbox outside gridview ?

Answer (score 2):

Since your label is inside your GridView, you have to go through the rows within the GridView. You can use GridView's RowDataBound event go through the rows and access the value of inner control. Something like this..

```
     Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)   
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then   
              If Not e.Row.DataItem Is Nothing Then   
                    Dim lbl As Label = CType(e.Row.Cells(1).FindControl("YourLabelName"), Label)   
                    If lbl.Text = "Copy" Then   
                         TextBox1.Text = lbl.Text 
                    End If   
              End If   
        End If
```

End Sub

or if you want to copy particular row value, then

```
    Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("GridView1"), GridView).Rows(0).FindControl("YourLabelName"), Label)
    TextBox1.Text = lbl.Text
```